# self.board.update_attributes returns undefined method `update_attributes'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

During create of a reply, I'm trying to update the board's :toppid column with the line `self.board.update_attributes(:toppid => reply_max.to_i + 1)`, however this returns `NoMethodError in RepliesController#create undefined method 'update_attributes' for nil:NilClass`

How can I properly update the `:toppid` column?

Rest of my code:

reply.rb:

```
class Reply < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :board
    belongs_to :post
  after_create :set_pid
  def set_pid
    reply_max = self.post.replies.maximum(:pid)
    board_max = self.board(:toppid)
    if board_max.to_i > reply_max.to_i
      self.update_attributes(:pid => board_max.to_i + 1)
      self.board.update_attributes(:toppid => board_max.to_i + 1)
    else
      self.update_attributes(:pid => reply_max.to_i + 1)
      self.board.update_attributes(:toppid => reply_max.to_i + 1)
    end
  end
end
```

replies_controller.rb:

```
class RepliesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @board = Board.friendly.find(params[:board_id])
    @post = @board.posts.friendly.find params[:post_id]
    @reply = @post.replies.create(reply_params)
    @post.touch
    redirect_to @board
  end
  private
    def reply_params
      params.require(:reply).permit(:name, :email, :subject, :comment, :reply_file)
    end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
  resources :boards, :path => '' do
    resources :posts, :path => 'thread' do
      resources :replies
```

Comment: By any chance is it `undefined method "update_attributes" for NilClass`? (It helps to post the full error message).

Comment: @AndrewSchwartz yes it is, sorry about that I also updated the post with it.

Comment: Cool! So if it's saying that `NilClass` (or, `nil`) does not have the method `update_attributes`, what do you think that means `self.board` is, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at your call to `@reply = @post.replies.create(reply_params)` your reply object never gets associated with a board object.

You probably want to use build instead. Something like:

```
@reply = @post.replies.build(reply_params)
@reply.board = @board
@reply.save
```

## Edit

From your comments, there seems to be a disconnect in what you want your model relationships to be and your above code. Using `belongs_to` means that you have a database level foreign key relationship between one model and another.

According to your comments, you don't want this. If this is indeed the case, get rid of the relationship and delegate `board` to `post`. Otherwise, fix your tables by doing what I initially suggested and adding a board_id to your replies_table.

Here is how you would write the delegation:

```
class Reply < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  after_create :set_pid
  delegate :board, to: :post

  def set_pid
    reply_max = self.post.replies.maximum(:pid)
    board_max = self.board(:toppid) # have no idea what you're trying to do here, but it's also a syntax error, maybe you mean to write: self.board.toppid
    if board_max.to_i > reply_max.to_i
      self.update_attributes(pid: board_max.to_i + 1)
      self.board.update_attributes(toppid: board_max.to_i + 1)
    else
      self.update_attributes(pid: reply_max.to_i + 1)
      self.board.update_attributes(toppid: reply_max.to_i + 1)
    end
  end
end
```

Also, assuming you have integer columns for `pid` and `toppid` (which it looks like in the `update_attributes` calls), your use of `to_i` is unnecessary.

Comment: I get the error: `can't write unknown attribute 'board_id'` highlighting `@reply.board = @board`

Comment: Sounds like something is also messed up with your schema, what does your migration to create the replies table look like?

Comment: @aidiah, specifically, do you have board_id defined on the replies table?

Comment: no, posts has the board_id column, replies has post_id

Comment: Then your model doesn't make sense. Above you have the Reply model with a `belongs_to :board` and are calling `self.board` from a reply object. If it doesn't have a board_id column then it can't have a direct association with a board object.

Comment: Added an explanation in an edit, but really, all of this kind of goes beyond the initial scope of your question, so if you have another question about model structure, please create another question rather than expanding scope in comments.